# SQL Constraint that checks if only one record exists and uses its value for table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create two SQL table right now that interact with each other and have been searching for an answer for quite some time. A little nudge towards the right direction would be highly appreciated.

In my case, I've got a table `Company` that has the following `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Company
      (CNr INTEGER NOT NULL,
       Name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       Manager VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       Area VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (FNr));
```

And a table `Employee` that is being created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
      (Name VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
       Age INTEGER NOT NULL,
       Company INTEGER NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (Name));
```

Now I'd like to create a way for `Company` to check, if there exists only one employee in `Employee` and, if so makes this employee a Manager in `Company`.

I was trying around with `SELECT CASE` but am not sure about my solution:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (1 = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee WHERE Company = CNr)
    THEN Manager = (SELECT Name FROM Manager WHERE Company = CNr);
    ELSE Manager = new.Manager;
END
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A primary key on name seems like a pretty horrible idea. Primary keys should be unique (which names are not) and should not change - which names do. It's also unclear in your question where you will be running this code. You mention a constraint, but nothing else seems to indicate that.

Comment: That is not what constraints do.  They do not change the data.  Perhaps you are thinking of a trigger.

Comment: constraint can not do this .u have to write a trigger i think because this is self checking procedure

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @TomH agreed. The key should have a different type. Re where it's supposed to run. I'm using an Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Just rephrased the question. Any hint on how a trigger solution could look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you don't use a constraint to update your data. You can use the following code to check if 1 employee exists in the employee table, and if he does, you place his name in all the rows in the column `Manager` of table `Company`.

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Employee LIMIT 2) = 1 THEN 
  (UPDATE Company SET manager = (SELECT Name FROM Employee))
END
```

If you only want to update certain rows of table `Company`, then include the `WHERE ...` clause with the condition that you want to decide which rows get updated:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Employee LIMIT 2) = 1 THEN 
  (UPDATE Company SET manager = (SELECT Name FROM Employee) WHERE ...)
END
```

*(replace ... with the condition)*

Let me know if that helped you.

Comment: What about a case like mine where I am using an API like PostGraphile which abstracts my ability to use SQL queries? 

Checks would be useful in this case since I can add this check as a constraint to my DB table in my workbench.